# Using regexp to filter an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter, lastindexof

I'm trying to use a RegExp in a `.filter()` method, the problem is that I am using `/g` on the regexp, so after the first iteration, the `.lasindex` is not longer 0 and I am getting `false` as result. Is there any way to reset the `.lastindex` during next iteration?

```
function dontGiveMeFive(start, end){
  var newArr = [];
  var re = new RegExp( "[^5]" , "g");

  for (i = start; i <= end; i++){
    newArr.push(i);
  }

  return newArr.filter(function(str){  
                  return  re.test(str);});
}
```

Examples:

```
newArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

true
false
true
false
false
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: I've had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703078/chrome-v8-bug-function-acting-different-after-being-called-a-2nd-time)  before. Is the g necessary? Also, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3703099/217867).

Comment: Jorge, try moving the RegEx declaration into the 2nd function instead of the first.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew This is not a duplicate, because Jorge is not using literal syntax. In his case, the RegEx is maintaining state because it is only declared once for all items filtered during one function call. It is closure issue.

Comment: @LonnieBest: As per my test, [it is a duplicate](https://jsfiddle.net/v2kx50zx/).

Comment: @LonnieBest is this case i want to use global, because i want it to match at digit with a 5 ( 5 , 15, 25, 35, 500, 5555).

Comment: Thanks @LonnieBest, changing the declaration into the 2nd function works well